# file_get_contents() find why not work

Tags: php, file-get-contents

```
<?

$ip = '95.79.1.36'; //russian ip for test
$str = 'http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip='.$ip;
$content = file_get_contents($str);
preg_match_all('#<country>(.*)(</country>)#Usi', $content, $matches); 
$country = $matches[0][0];
preg_match_all('#<city>(.*)(</city>)#Usi', $content, $matches); 
$city = $matches[0][0];
if($country == 'RU'){
echo 'City: '.$city.'';
}else{
echo 'Country: '.$country.'';
}

?>
```

The problem is **$country == 'RU'** , not work, my question is why ?

Thanks )))

Comment: The main problem is, there is no question

Comment: probably because what you are trying to get content of is not a file on the server on which this code is running. It should be a path `/home/php/index.php` UNLESS your php is properly configured.

Comment: Start using error detection and handling

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier `file_get_contents()` supports http stream wrappers and will happily retrieve a URL _if PHP is configured to permit it_ via `allow_url_fopen`.

Comment: @Michael oh that's nice! never did that though.

Comment: I think he means that $country equals 'RU', but it skips the if, so this script shows "Country: RU"

Comment: yes @AlexSorinDachin that what i mean

Comment: This happends because $country is actually '<country>RU</country>'

Comment: You can put $country = $matches[1][0] instead of [0][0]

Comment: @Alex Sorin Dachin thanks! work good with $matches[1][0]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be parsing HTML/XHTML/XML with Regex. See: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

I recommend using PHP's SimpleXML parser. The following worked for me:

```
<?php
$ip = '95.79.1.36'; //russian ip for test
$str = 'http://ipgeobase.ru:7020/geo?ip='.$ip;

$results = simplexml_load_file($str);
$country = $results->ip->country;
$city = $results->ip->city;

if($country == 'RU'){
echo 'City: '.$city.'';
}else{
echo 'Country: '.$country.'';
}

?>
```

Comment: thank you very much, work good with add iconv("UTF-8", "WINDOWS-1251", $country)

Comment: No problem! Glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 3):

Your server probably does not `allow_url_fopen` (php.ini directive). Anyway, the technology you are looking for for this particular case is cURL : https://php.net/curl.

I'd be delighted to provide more explanations about your code specifically, and even provide cURL code samples, once you'll have edited your question properly, with more information and attempts resulting of your efforts.

Comment: the code work very good, i see the results if i dosn't use if($country == 'RU'), i don't understand if i see $country result RU, why not work with check *sorry for my english) thanks